# Replacing tip on Weller WHS40 soldering iron?

Tags: soldering, replacement, soldering-iron-station

I've had Weller WHS 40 soldering station for some 20-ish years or so, used purely as hobbyist few times a year mostly for work on simple through-hole components. Lately, the (still original, never changed) tip has become damaged as pictured (it is standard "flat screwdriver" type, not some special U-shaped tip).

[image: damaged tip]

Base of the tip has diameter of 3.5mm, and I seem to have found them online for about 20 EUR for 3 pieces (which looks reasonable to me). However, the tip seems to be held in place by very small screw, which, as you can imagine, has become quite attached to the heater. I've tried to unscrew it with small screwdriver, but it doesn't budge and I'm reluctant to apply more force, as even this seems to damage it.

The question is, how to dislodge the screw safely so I can replace the tip; or if can't be done, how can I remove and replace it with something reasonable available? Is it worth it? The station have served me well, but if if it is not worth it, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Maybe try removing the screw while the iron is heated? It may simply be unremovable at this point due to all the crud from oxidation and soldering.  I wouldn't worry about preserving the screw as long as it comes out. Just get a replacement unless the manufacturer was devlish and customed the thread. That "damage' just looks like the iron in the tip dissolved into the solder. I had that happen once on an iron after a year of using it to solder heavy wires using lead free solder. It had developed a nice semi-circle cut out suited to the shape of the wire I was soldering which was just as well.

Comment: I'd try some penetrating oil, and running the iron through some heat cycles, ultimately trying to unscrew it while hot.

Comment: @HeathRaftery When you say "penetrating oil", is it something like `WD-40`? I've though of that, but I've been afraid if it (when heated) won't create even more crud and smoke?

Comment: WD-40 is not penetrating oil, it is a Water Displacement oil, ergo the WD.  Plus-Gas is a penetrating oil, there are many others...

Comment: I was thinking of dunking it some type of weak acid to remove any oxidation.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry, I ask because I'm in EU and never heard of Plus-Gas (much less seen it for buying), but looking at [Plus-Gas](http://www.plusgas.co.uk/about-plusgas/) description page it also says water-displacement, protective film,  destroys rust etc. as does [WD-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40/) page - difference being we have WD-40 around here.

Comment: WD-40 will do, though your local hardware store might have some better options. WD-40 is good at dissolving rusty particulates, but more specialised penetrating oils will wick into tighter gaps and lubricate. Don't worry about the crud and smoke - they wont stop you loosening the thread, which is the goal here.